# Using scipy.optimize for a non algebraic function

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

i want to try to use Scipy.optimze to build a solver for a Data Mining Tool.

the function i have to define before using the minimize function is something like this, it is not an algebraic function- just a callable query to another program that gives an ouput estimation:

```
def query(x):
    import numpy as np
    file_direc_in="path_to_input_file.csv"
    file_direc_out="path_to_output_file.csv"

    x=np.array([[1,2,4,6]])
    with open(file_direc_in, 'w') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, x, delimiter=';', fmt='%.3f',newline='\r\n')
    f.close()
    os.system(Dataset_query.bat)
    #batch file takes the array i wrote to from input_file and estimates a result
    #afterwards the output will be taken from the output file:
    f = open(file_direc_out,'r')
    out = np.array([[float(f.readlines()[0])]])
    f.close()
    return out


from scipy.optimize import minimize
x0=np.array([[1,1,1,1]])#first guess
res=minimize(query,x0,method='nelder-mead',callback=True)
```

After I call the `res`part I see what I usually see in my console: the Data Mining tool answers my queries but `res`becomes a loop with the `x0`array being the input on every cycle - I thought on every cicle another array is tested by the `minimize` function.

what am I doing wrong?
how can I change my `query`function to achieve a function scipy will minimize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def query(x):
    import numpy as np
    file_direc_in="path_to_input_file.csv"
    file_direc_out="path_to_output_file.csv"

    x=np.array([[1,2,4,6]])
```

Important part:

```
    x=np.array([[1,2,4,6]])
```

You throw away your input! Don't do that, and see what happens.

Comment: if i delete the line where i define `x` i get an error from my Data Mining Tool... well i cannot delete this line cause i write the`x`to a csv file... `np.savetxt(f, x, delimiter=';', fmt='%.3f',newline='\r\n')` and i guess `minimize`does not change my x - and i do not know how to make this clear to scipy- all the example i saw, where different.

Comment: @user2956831: You may be using your data mining tool wrong, then. There is absolutely no way you should be throwing away the value of `x` passed into your function.

Comment: they had an algebraic expression like:                                    `def rosen(x):
    #The Rosenbrock function
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)`

Comment: but `query(x)` expects a variable named `x` or in this case an array `x` if i am not wrong if i omit `x` than getting an error is quite logic

Comment: @user2956831: The array `x` should be the one passed into the function. You shouldn't redefine `x` inside the function, ignoring the value passed to it.

Comment: maybe i found a mistake, looking in my input file, i see that the array is written as a column and not as a row (what it should be to get an answer, and what it was before i tried to use `optimize` )

Comment: i omitted the `x`definition in the function and changed something in the part where i write the array to a file, but now i seem to be in an infinite query loop the values in the input and output files did not change in the files after stopping the loop by manual exit the program

Comment: ok, it seems to work now, but my real problem has 20 independent variables and i have not set any constraints... so this is why it needs so much time - i will work on getting some tasks that make sense to try the optimization tools - i just wanted to get an example how i can combine my function with the optimization in scipy - thanks for the help!